# In C# what is the difference between passing a pointer to a struct and using `ref` or `in` on read only structs?

Tags: c#

If you have a struct that is read only how does passing this struct in methods differ between sending a pointer to it and using `ref` or `in` ?

For example:

```
public readonly struct Node {

    private readonly float2 _position;
    public float2 Position => _position;

    public Node(float2 p) {
       _position = p;
    }
}
```

I could create a pointer to it defined in some class for example:

```
fixed (Node* t = &_node)
{
    _ptr = t;
}
```

Then pass `_ptr` to a method such as:

```
public unsafe void DoSomething(Node* nodePtr);
```

How does that differ to not using a pointer and using methods defined with `ref` and `in` like below:

```
public void DoSomething(ref Node node);
public void DoSomething(in Node node);
```

I'm pretty sure defensive copies are not done for `ref` and `in` on read-only structs, unless I am mistaken? So are these identical ?

Comment: `ref` doesn't require `unsafe` compilation.

Comment: So they are identical, except ref saves me the pain of having to deal with unsafe context?

Comment: No, they are not identical - for example, the exported IL metadata will be different.

Comment: Well then its not clear on what the difference is under the hood. I can modify the struct via pointer the same way as with `ref` so they seem the same to me. Is `in` also the same then or does that create a defensive copy?

Comment: `ref` managed pointers are safe, so the GC knows what's going on. Unmanaged pointers are unsafe, so all bets are off. GC may move the location of your struct and the pointer would corrupt memory, although that is unlikely to happen with structs which are local variables but it may happen with structs stored in fields of objects. You prevent issues by using `fixed` but why bother with unmanaged pointers at all? Why would you use `unsafe` if you didn't have to? `fixed` also has an overhead: it trammels GC from moving stuff, and has a management overhead

Comment: @Charlieface well the why is not relevant right now, beyond the fact i only use structs for doing work on data. I am just trying to understand the difference. If a struct is stored in an array, would `ref` allow you to edit the struct in the array without making a copy and replacing it ?

Comment: Yes, you can take `ref` from an array. You cannot take from a `List` or other wrapper object, unless they use `ref` returns.

Comment: Ah good point i didn't think of that. That means I'll have to stick to pointers at least for dealing with collections of structs.

Comment: @WDUK " That means I'll have to stick to pointers at least for dealing with collections of structs." - no, you shouldn't. Stick to using only `ref` types. Stop using `unsafe` because of _your feelings_. It's called "unsafe" for a reason: because you shouldn't be using it, and Charlieface correctly points out the performance benefits of using `ref` instead of `fixed`. You can't take a pointer to a struct element in a `List<T>`, so there's _zero_ advantages to using `unsafe` over `ref` types.

Comment: @Charlieface Since .Net 5 you can get `ref` to values of `List` (and `Dictionary`) using `CollectionsMarshal`

Comment: With your own collections you can use the new `ref` return feature, as mentioned. Arguably if you are using built-in collections you don't care majorly about performance of GC, so you shouldn't be worrying about pointers in the first place. I think this all smells of premature optimization

Comment: @Dai I'm currently storing pointers in a list, the pointers are created in classes, I'm not doing pointers to elements in a list since the reesize would break them, that was an issue I was having during threading. In my situation the pointer list is a native list on the stack. My threads need to return links to the right node, not a copy of it.

Comment: @WDUK There's no such thing as a "native list on the stack". Please clarify by showing us the exact data-types (in their source-language) you're working with. And it's probably a bad idea to reference native stack-allocated objects from C# code (and vice-versa) because of how the CLR works: the only safe-way is heap (or other non-stack-based storage) references wrapped in an `IDisposable` that never `free` (or equivalent) until after the CLR-based consumer says so.

Comment: Ah my bad I meant, my list is a list of pointers to structs, stack was a wrong word. So a resize doesn't break the pointers. Then I can edit structs via `->` in parallel via threading and structs allow me to tightly pack my data for better performance. Right now using unsafe I got it down from 4ms to 0.0001ms. Then heard about `ref` and wasn't sure if it was the same as a pointer.

Comment: @WDUK If you care about performance, use C/C++/Rust - not C#

Comment: No i would rather keep it all in C#. Changing language doesn't really retract from the problems that I would have in C#.